# Yii2 console code generator not generating query model

Tags: yii2

I am trying to generate model class with query class, GUI gii works fine for me. But when I tried via console, It only creates `modelClass` not `queryClass`. Here is my code snippets.

```
php yii gii/model --tableName=page_resource --modelClass=PageResource --ns="backend\models" --queryClass=PageResource --queryNs="backend\models\query"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
--generateQuery=1
```

It's `0` by default.

Run

```
php yii help gii/model
```

for list of all options.